# How can I make variables from system.in public

Tags: java, if-statement

After I check to make sure the value of the variable is in the correct form, and then declare the variable how can I make that public, so I don't have to nest all of my code? For example

```
public class Universalgravitation {
    static Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {           
        double G = .00000000006667;
        System.out.println("Keep in mind the upper limit for all of the values is 2 billion ");
        System.out.print("What is the mass of the first object? ");
        if(userInput.hasNextInt())
        {               
            int Mass1 = userInput.nextInt();
            System.out.print("What is the mass of the second object? ");
        if(userInput.hasNextInt())
        {               
            int Mass2 = userInput.nextInt();
            System.out.print("What is the radial distance between the two objects? ");
        if(userInput.hasNextInt())
        {               
            int Dist = userInput.nextInt();
            System.out.println("The gravitational force in newtons is: " + (G * Mass1 * Mass2) / (Dist * Dist));
        }
        }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you check if it has a next double, and then read an int?

Comment: Thanks I don't know why I didn't catch that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0020__Language/VariableScopeinablock.htm) is a quick link describing scoping in Java. [This](http://www.java-made-easy.com/variable-scope.html) link describes it a little clearer, but the first is closer to what you are looking for.

A Brief example:

```
class Something{
    public void example(){
        int value=1;
        System.out.println("value from before a block: "+value);
            {
                value=2;
                System.out.println("value from inside a block: "+value);
            }
        System.out.println("value from after a block: "+value);
    }
}
```

Also, I do not want to risk confusing you, or jumping ahead of what you have learned in class, so I am mostly bringing this up for future reference, but another thing to consider is storing the values in an Object.

For example you could do something like the following:

```
class Foo{
    static final double G = .00000000006667;
    private int Mass1;
    private int Mass2;
    private int Dist=1;//defaulting to avoid division by zero

    public int getMass1(){return mass1;}
    public void setMass1(int mass1){this.mass1=mass1;}
    ....

    public double getGravitationalForce(){
        return (G * Mass1 * Mass2) / (Dist * Dist);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to have unchanging values that are somewhat global in nature, declare them final and initialize them either in the declaration or in a constructor.  Also, try to use a meaningful name (the choice of name in my example below may not be correct).  For example

```
public class blammy
{
  private static final double coefficientOfGravity = .00000000006667;


 ... blah blah ...

 System.out.println("blammy: " + (coefficientOfGravity * mass1 * mass2) / (dist * dist));

... blah blah ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Declare your variables as static Global variables to start with then assign values to them like so.

```
public class Universalgravitation {
    static Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

    static double G

    static int Mass1;
    static int Mass2;
    static int Dist;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {           
        G = .00000000006667;
        System.out.println("Keep in mind the upper limit for all of the values is 2 billion ");
        System.out.print("What is the mass of the first object? ");
        if(userInput.hasNextInt())
        {               
            Mass1 = userInput.nextInt();
            System.out.print("What is the mass of the second object? ");
            if(userInput.hasNextDouble())
            {               
                Mass2 = userInput.nextInt();
                System.out.print("What is the radial distance between the two objects? ");
                if(userInput.hasNextDouble())
                {               
                    Dist = userInput.nextInt();
                    System.out.println("The gravitational force in newtons is: " + (G * Mass1 * Mass2) / (Dist * Dist));
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Bad advise. It is enough if he declares the variables at the beginning of the method.